# Modify docking layout in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I have a `SplitContainer` on my form that has its Dock property set to **Fill**. It contains several child controls, many of which have event handlers attached to them. Later I decide to put a `StatusStrip` at the bottom of my form. Guess what, I can't set the `StatusStrip` to dock to the bottom of my form. The `SplitContainer` will continue to Fill the entire form. Even though the `StatusStrip` apparently gets docked to the bottom, it actually hides the bottom part of the `SplitContainer` behind it.

The only around it is to CUT the `SplitContainer` and then PASTE it back. Cutting the `SplitContainer` makes the `StatusStrip` the only control on my form and thus lets it capture the bottom docking. Afterwards, pasting the `SplitContainer` allows it to fill the remaining area. In short, docking uses First Come, First Serve method.

Now since my controls have lots of event handlers attached to them, cutting and pasting becomes a nightmare for me. Having my project in C# means I have to attach all those event handlers manually.

Is there a better work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a z-order issue between the splitter and the statusstrip. When you have a control you want to dock fill and one or more controls you want to dock top, left, right, or bottom, you have to have the fill control be the first in the z-order.

The better way is to open the Document Outline tool, select the SplitContainer and use the up or down buttons to change its z-order.

I should add that in Winforms the z-order is specified by the order in which you add controls to the Controls collection. That order determines the order the associated system controls are created, hence their z-order. Using the Document Outline tool to alter z-order simply causes the generated code to be re-ordered.